# How to add local Flutter package to another project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[image]

I'd like to add a local package to my android studio project. Previously Android Studio automatically suggested adding the package to my local workspace. Right now I don't see that option. In this example, I'd like to add a "hello" package to the root of my project just like "flutter_helper".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File -> Project Structure... -> Modules -> Add Content Root

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to move it to the same root folder in which your project is located by yourself.

```
<MY_FLUTTER_PROJECTS_FOLDER>
    eat_well
    hello
    flutter_helper
```